# How to refresh tablelayoutpanel contents in user control on button click

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, tablelayoutpanel

I have a button click event in one user control that will deduct 1 from the stock of ingredients in tbl_ingredients whenever it matches the ingredient found in string array ings.

```
private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, string[] ings)
{
   foreach (string s in ings)
   {
      string qry = "UPDATE tbl_ingredients SET inv_stock = inv_stock -1 WHERE inv_name = '" + s + "'";
      SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(qry, myConnection);
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

and a dynamically created tablelayoutpanel (to display all the ingredients and their respective total stock) in another user control

```
myConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.sqlite3");
string qry = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ingredients ORDER BY inv_name";
string qry2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ingredients";
SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand(qry, myConnection);
SQLiteCommand myCommand2 = new SQLiteCommand(qry2, myConnection);

openConnection();
int row = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand2.ExecuteScalar());
SQLiteDataReader result = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
string[] itemname = new string[row];
string[] totalstock = new string[row];
int cnt = 0;
if (result.HasRows)
{
   while (result.Read())
   {
      itemname[cnt] = result["inv_name"].ToString();
      totalstock[cnt] = result["inv_stock"].ToString();
      cnt++;
   }
}
//tlb_inventory is the name of the tablelayoutpanel in windows form
tbl_inventory.ColumnCount = 2;
tbl_inventory.RowCount = row;
tbl_inventory.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Item" }, 0, 0);
tbl_inventory.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Total Stock" }, 1, 0);
for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < row + 1; i++, j++)
{
   tbl_inventory.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = itemname[j], AutoSize = true }, 0, i);
   tbl_inventory.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = totalstock[j], AutoSize = true }, 1, i);
}

closeConnection();
```

Whenever I click on the button, it should update the contents of the table in real-time. The issue is that I have to re-run the program in order for it to display the updated contents of the table. Is there a function or something that will make the user control and its contents refresh after button click?

Comment: There is no any method called on your `btn_confirm_Click` method that refreshes your table. Where do you call your second code block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to set the name property to the labels control

```
 tbl_inventory.Controls.Add(new Label() { Name = "Total_"+ itemname[j], Text = totalstock[j], AutoSize = true }, 1, i);
```

and then at the button_click event inside foreach loop add:

```
 Label c = (tbl_inventory.Controls.Find("Total_" + s, true).First() as Label);
 var total = Convert.ToInt32(c.Text);
 c.Text = (total++).ToString();
```